# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 () asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am find out bids table to highest bidder to all product.

If wanted to find out list of bids then run it.

but here is problem to fixed.

my Action method

```
public ActionResult AllWinner()
        {
            MyDealDbContext db = new MyDealDbContext();    
            var model = db.bids.GroupBy(x => x.ProductId).Select(x => new { ProductId = x.Key, BidsPrice = x.Max(m => m.BidsPrice) }).ToList();            
            return View(model);
        }
```

and view

```
@model IEnumerable<MyDeal.Models.BidsInformation.Bids>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AllWinner";
}

<h2>AllWinner</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Customer.FirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Product.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BidsPrice)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BidsTime)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Customer.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BidsPrice)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BidsTime)
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

when it is loaded Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ().how can solve

Comment: How do you call the action _AllWinner_? How is named your View? Do you have it in a subfolder of the Views folder with the name equal to the Controller name?

Comment: my controller is dashboard so i call https://localhost:44310/Admin/DashBoard/AllWinner and view is AllWinner.cshtml

Comment: What is _Admin_ before the Controller name?

Comment: admin is area name

Answer (score 1):

[W3.org](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html) defines Http Status Code : 500 as "The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request."

this is usually means an exception occurred in the server side code ,however it's hard to guess where exactly it's happening , it could be the connection to the db , serializing the data , rendering the view

the good news is since this is a localhost it won't be hard to figure it out .

first in visual studio go to Debug => Windows => Exception => then check the common language runtime exceptions option (make sure it has a correct/yes mark next to it )

now your debugger will starting catching more types of exception hopefully it will throw a specific error message that we can then try to solve

and you can always use breakpoints in these kind of situations to confirm that the request reach the controller at least